# AVX issue when installing Kite - AI assistant

Tags: cpu

I'm trying to install Kite - coding assistant for Python and JS, but on start I'm getting message that my CPU does not support AVX instruction set, and that this set is supported on most CPUs built after 2012. I have Intel Pentium G4400 which is from mid 2015. I'm wondering if this option is maybe disabled in UEFI by default or something, and is it possible to solve this issue.

Comment: Intel lists their CPU specs on their site, and the CPUs that introduced AVX for Intel were the Sandy Bridge line which came before your Skylake chip. You should start by updating your BIOS.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that

Comment: After updating BIOS to the latest version problem still persists, in the meantime I also tried `bcdedit /set xsavedisable 0` but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I run on this issue again so I want to share what I found out. Shortly - This CPU does not support AVX and AVX2 despite some websites and specs say it does.
To check this (with python):

```
pip install cpuid
```

run the following:

```
from cpuid import *

def _is_set(id, reg_idx, bit):
    regs = cpuid(id)

    if (1 << bit) & regs[reg_idx]:
        return "Yes"
    else:
        return "--"

print("Vendor ID         : %s" % cpu_vendor())
print("CPU name          : %s" % cpu_name())
print("Microarchitecture : %s%s" % cpu_microarchitecture())
print("Vector instructions supported:")
print("SSE       : %s" % _is_set(1, 3, 25))
print("SSE2      : %s" % _is_set(1, 3, 26))
print("SSE3      : %s" % _is_set(1, 2, 0))
print("SSSE3     : %s" % _is_set(1, 2, 9))
print("SSE4.1    : %s" % _is_set(1, 2, 19))
print("SSE4.2    : %s" % _is_set(1, 2, 20))
print("SSE4a     : %s" % _is_set(0x80000001, 2, 6))
print("AVX       : %s" % _is_set(1, 2, 28))
print("AVX2      : %s" % _is_set(7, 1, 5))
print("BMI1      : %s" % _is_set(7, 1, 3))
print("BMI2      : %s" % _is_set(7, 1, 8))
```

Now it is clear, and unfortunately, AVX and AVX2 are not supported.